# Temporarily attach wood or vinyl flooring to a stage

Tags: wood, linoleum

I'm currently working on designing a theatre set. Our director would like a portion of the stage to be white. We have a limited run & as such don't have the time to paint the parts of the stage white (from black) & repaint before we need to get out.

Instead, we plan to lay down a thin piece of wood painted white or white lino. I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a recommended type of wood to use?
2. How can we attach wood/lino to the stage without damaging the stage?

Comment: I've seen temporary flooring put down on a stage in preparation for a ballet performance.  It's black.  I think they tape it down.  It might be expensive.  I don't know if it comes in other colors. // Maybe you could use some kind of tape, applied in slightly overlapping rows.  At first I was thinking of electrical tape, which is easy to remove, but then I came across something called vinyl tape on Amazon.  You'd have to ask whether it leaves a residue and whether it's easy to pull off.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We managed to do by purchasing a roll of white vinyl dance floor from Harlequin and attaching it to the stage using floor tape. It was relatively easy to lay - we cut it using a Stanley knife and with ~10 students attached it to the floor over about an hour.

Our choice was primarily driven by budget, time constraints and limited woodworking experience - it was a project for a Uni opera society - but the vinyl worked great for us! if we were to do it again, the only thing I'd change would be taking more time to attach it to ensure it's completely flat.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to answer your question (and accept it)!

Answer (score 0):

How tough do you need it to be?
Pressure sensitive glue is probably a good attach method.

Lino will probably lie flat; Vinyl flooring (a different product) probably will not.

Vinyl sign writer's film may be a good option.

Painted builder's paper held down with gaffer's tape at the seams and edges is much cheaper and  will be easier to remove.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably lay either actual vinyl flooring underlayment (1/4" birch plywood), or, if budget is a strict concern, use luan plywood. The latter isn't suitable for permanent flooring since it tends to stain flooring over time and may have minor voids in its plies.

You could use a strong tape to join the plywood, then lay the vinyl using standard troweled adhesive. When the show is done, simply cut the floor at the plywood seams and stack it up.

You'll want to use a suitable transition at the edge to prevent trips. Total height will be about 3/8".